# newsletter unsubscribe

Tags: landing-page

I edited my question in order to make it more understandable.
My goal is to create 2 custom cloud pages to unsubscribe the users.
In the first one I have a form where the user can choose the reasons why it is unsubscribing; while in the second one I used amscript to unsubscribe the user.

These are are the steps:

1. the user clicks on the unsubscribe link of the email and gets a redirect to the first cloud page.

the first cloud page looks like that:

```html
form action="" class="form">
              <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="unsub_reason" id="first_option" value="reason one">
                    <label for="first_option">reason one</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="unsub_reason" id="second_option" value="reason two">
                    <label for="second_option">reason two</label>
                </div>
<input type="submit" name="submit_event"
             </form>
```

What I want to do is:

1. get the option the user choose and store them.
2. insert all the answers i get into a DE in marketing cloud with a function, when the user clicks submit. (I also want to put an a tag into the input, because i want to redirect the user to a second cloud page that actually performs the unsubscribe event)

My second cloud page has just a p tag that say that the unsubscription is a success, and it has this ampscript that I checked already and it works:

```
VAR @sid, @jid, @reason, @lue, @lue_prop, @lue_statusCode, @overallStatus, @requestId, @Response, @Status, @Error

SET @sid = IIF(Empty(RequestParameter("email_address")),RequestParameter("current_email_address"),RequestParameter("email_address"))
SET @jid = RequestParameter("jobid")
SET @listid = RequestParameter("listid")
SET @batchid = RequestParameter("batchid")
SET @reason = "Profile Center Unsubscribe"

SET @lue = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent")

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @sid)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "JobID")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @jid)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "ListID")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @listid)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "BatchID")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @batchid)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "Reason")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @reason)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

/* You must set ClientID when working with On Your Behalf accounts
var @lue_oyb;
set @lue_oyb = CreateObject('ClientID')
SetObjectProperty(@lue_oyb, 'ID', @mid)
SetObjectProperty(@lue, 'Client', @lue_oyb)
*/

SET @lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@lue, @overallStatus, @requestId)

SET @Response = Row(@lue_statusCode, 1)
SET @Status = Field(@Response,"StatusMessage")
SET @Error = Field(@Response,"ErrorCode")
```

Comment: Please add all relevant code to your question.

Comment: @FelixvanHove thank you for your answer, I edited my question, I hope it is more understandable now